# Approach of training a large image data set using keras, running out of memory

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

I'm new in computer vision and ML area, I'm trying to develop an image recognition model that I'm training with a large data set of images (50 000 images, 18 GB in size) but on a laptop like Acer Predator that has 16 GB memory and 7th gen Core i7 cpu, GTX 1060 Nvidia, I'm running out of memory even though I'm using GPU on tensorflow.

If I train this model with few images like 2000, to 4000 then it's working  fine. It seems there is some wrong approach I'm using to train this model but I'm not able to figure out the right approach. I think if I load images into small multiple batches and then train then it could help but I don't know how to achieve this.

Below is the code snippet of my train model request.

My train.py is as below

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Agg")
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from keras.preprocessing import image
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from pyimagesearch.smallervggnet import SmallerVGGNet
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from imutils import paths
import numpy as np
import random
import pickle
import os
import json
import tensorflow as tf
with tf.device('/device:CPU:0'):
a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2], name='b')
c = tf.matmul(a, b)
#config = tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True)

session = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
print(session.run(c))

with open('conf/conf.json') as f:
config = json.load(f)

# config variables
dataset     = config["dataset"]
model_path      = config["model"]
labelbin   = config["labelbin"]
plot   = config["plot"]
test_image     = config["test_image"]
print('dataset: %s '+dataset)

EPOCHS = 75
INIT_LR = 1e-3
BS = 32
IMAGE_DIMS = (96, 96, 3)

# grab the image paths and randomly shuffle them
print("[INFO] loading images...")
imagePaths = sorted(paths.list_images(dataset))
random.seed(42)
random.shuffle(imagePaths)

# initialize the data and labels
data = []
labels = []
for imagePath in imagePaths:
 img = image.load_img(imagePath,target_size=(IMAGE_DIMS[1], IMAGE_DIMS[0]))     
 img = img_to_array(img)
 data.append(img)
 l = label = imagePath.split(os.path.sep)[-2].split("_")
 labels.append(l)

print("[INFO] images loading done...")

# scale the raw pixel intensities to the range [0, 1]
data = np.array(data, dtype="float") / 255.0
labels = np.array(labels)
print("[INFO] data matrix: {} images ({:.2f}MB)".format(
len(imagePaths), data.nbytes / (1024 * 1000.0)))

# binarize the labels using scikit-learn's special multi-label
# binarizer implementation
print("[INFO] class labels:")
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
labels = mlb.fit_transform(labels)

# loop over each of the possible class labels and show them
for (i, label) in enumerate(mlb.classes_):
print("{}. {}".format(i + 1, label))

# partition the data into training and testing splits using 80% of
# the data for training and the remaining 20% for testing
(trainX, testX, trainY, testY) = train_test_split(data,
labels, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# construct the image generator for data augmentation
aug = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=25, width_shift_range=0.1,
 height_shift_range=0.1, shear_range=0.2, zoom_range=0.2,
 horizontal_flip=True, fill_mode="nearest")

 # initialize the model using a sigmoid activation as the final layer
 # in the network so we can perform multi-label classification
 print("[INFO] compiling model...")
 model = SmallerVGGNet.build(
 width=IMAGE_DIMS[1], height=IMAGE_DIMS[0],
 depth=IMAGE_DIMS[2], classes=len(mlb.classes_),
 finalAct="sigmoid")

 # initialize the optimizer (SGD is sufficient)
  opt = Adam(lr=INIT_LR, decay=INIT_LR / EPOCHS)

 # compile the model using binary cross-entropy rather than
 # categorical cross-entropy -- this may seem counterintuitive for
 # multi-label classification, but keep in mind that the goal here
 # is to treat each output label as an independent Bernoulli
 # distribution
   model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer=opt,
   metrics=["accuracy"])

 # train the network
   print("[INFO] training network...")
 H = model.fit_generator(
   aug.flow(trainX, trainY, batch_size=BS),
   validation_data=(testX, testY),use_multiprocessing=True,
   steps_per_epoch=len(trainX) // BS,
   epochs=EPOCHS, verbose=1)

 # save the model to disk
  print("[INFO] serializing network...")
  model.save(model_path)

 # save the multi-label binarizer to disk
 print("[INFO] serializing label binarizer...")
 f = open(labelbin, "wb")
 f.write(pickle.dumps(mlb))
 f.close()
```

**Conf.json** is:

```
{
"dataset"         : "data-images",
"model"         : "output/fashion.model",
"labelbin"         : "output/mlb.pickle",
"plot"           :  "output/plot.png",
"test_image"           :  "examples/example_01.jpg"
}
```

Comment: Your setup looks fine regarding the generation of the training data. But the way you create your validation set it becomes quite large when you use 50k images. You can use a data generator for the validation data, as well. See [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2702).

Comment: Hi James, Thanks a lot for your response. I think I've figure out my problem and that is within the following block: for imagePath in imagePaths:
 img = image.load_img(imagePath,target_size=(IMAGE_DIMS[1], IMAGE_DIMS[0]))     
 img = img_to_array(img)
 data.append(img)
 l = label = imagePath.split(os.path.sep)[-2].split("_")
 labels.append(l) .  The major culprit here is data.append(img) which is loading all images 19 GB on RAM, How can I avoid this situation? I want something like aug.flow_from_directory() but in this approach how ti train custom lables Iike i'm doing in the above

Comment: James edited your answer and I posted the comment ;) I didn't see that you load all the images at once, this is infeasible for such a large dataset. What I usually do is write my own data-generator (only a function that has to have the keyworld `yield` followed by the created batch at the end of the method. In the rest of the code, i.e. when passing the training and validation set to the network, I only use lists of the image filenames. Your computer is able to easily handle 50k strings but not the loaded images. You load the images inside the data-generator on-demand.

Comment: You can have a look at my [6D pose estimation network](https://github.com/Sonnentierchen/flowerpower_nn/blob/master/python/model/model.py), check the `data_generator` method and where it is used. I adapted the generator from [Matterport's Mask RCNN implementation](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN). You can create a data generator for the validation set, as well, such that you create ALL images on-demand when Keras requests them.

Comment: Hi Florian, Thanks for your reply, I've got through he 6D pose estimation network but this is quite complex at my level  as of now :) I request you if you can give me a small code snippet of how can I create a data generator for the validation set for all my images from my example. Thanks

Comment: Hello, I'm still not able to get any clue on this yet, can anyone help me to give me an example on this, I tried lots of workarounds but it's not working. Please explain me with some simple example

Comment: Well, you need a class that has access to the list of strings which stores the image filenames. Then inside there needs to be a function that loads the images on a 4-dimensional array of [batch size, image height, image width, channels (RGB)]. E.g. when you want a batch size of 10 load the next ten images. Then, when you're finished loading the images, return them by coding `yield images`. You pass this class as the data generator to kera's `fit_generaror` function.

Comment: Maybe have a look at this tutorial https://medium.com/@ensembledme/writing-custom-keras-generators-fe815d992c5a. Or if you don't succeed maybe write a new question and show what you have tried so far and what exactly isn't working.

Comment: Hi Florian, thanks for your response, I've gone through and observed that I've to replace image generator with custom image generator, I request you to have a look on attached link https://drive.google.com/open?id=14F4e5NypYmJ07-ioq6R24dEr7foMCp8C where I'm trying to achieve in MyGenerator.py, will really appreciate if you can integrate Mygenerator.py in my train.py. Thanks

Comment: Hi Jitender, sorry but I won't do all the coding for you. This forum is there to answer specific questions and not produce whole programs. But I found another link by googeling (which you can do, as well) here: https://www.kaggle.com/ezietsman/simple-keras-model-with-data-generator. This is a fairly simple example of a data generator, which should show you how to integrate a generator. If you have _specific_ questions about a _certain_ problem you can post it to SO.